# using form labels produces a different output than just displaying directly

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I don't understand why this happens.

So if I have the following text: "A. This is an answer choice." If I display this text like so:

```
<%= ff.label :content, :value => answer.content %>
```

The output is:

"This is an answer choice"

If I just simply do:

```
<%= answer.content %>
```

The output is:

"A. This is an answer choice."

The latter is what I want, and I don't understand why this is occurring at all.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I wasn't using radio buttons correctly. Doing `<%= ff.label :content, answer.content, :value => answer.content %>` fixes this issue.